# Mysql multiply number of same records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, records

Here is a simple query

```
$fetch_comb = mysql_query("SELECT code_id , atb_name_id FROM products_attributes pa WHERE pa.products_id = $products_id ");
```

I have an output like this

```
-----------------------
| code_id |atb_name_id|
-----------------------
| 1       |    31     |
| 2       |    31     |
| 3       |    31     |
| 4       |    31     |
| 5       |    34     |
| 6       |    34     |
| 7       |    37     |
| 8       |    37     |
| 9       |    37     |

column `atb_name_id` has
"31" = 4 records, 
"34" = 2 records and
"37" = 3 records
```

I want to multiply these records in the query i.e  4 * 2 * 3 = 24

Comment: That is great. What is your question? Remember you must show effort, others are not here to write **your** code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `PRODUCT` function in SQL, but there is a [workaround](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/166184). You can try this:

```
SELECT CEILING(EXP(SUM(LOG(cnt))))
FROM (
    SELECT atb_name_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM products_attributes pa 
    WHERE pa.products_id = $products_id
    GROUP BY atb_name_id
) t
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62d7a/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Felix Pamittan